# 1.9.4.3 One Page checkout stuck on step 4 when entering credit card but Paypal still works

Tags: magento-1.9

I've exhausted the forums and keep in mind I'm new to Magento but I've added the codes to the multiple phtml files to enable for the formkey validation. I've been unable to get that to work. With the formkey validation disabled, I can get to the payment section and checkout through Paypal but if I try to enter credit card info, the continue button doesn't do anything but will validate that cc #'s align with visa/mc type.

I've looked at opocheckout.js & Ive checed out the methods.phtml and info.phtml files to make sure they are configured correctly according to the forums I've seen referencing similar problems.

Not seeing any new errors in the system or exceptions logs.